# ZeroMQ not working when sending request over HTTP

Tags: php, zeromq, ratchet

I have a WebSocket server (modified Ratchet) that uses ZermoMQ for pushing messages to the server. Recently I've migrated the server onto a new VPS.

The implementation is identical but for some reason when I request a PHP script over HTTP, then ZeroMQ doesn't send the payload to the WebSocket server but when I run the script through the terminal, it works.

This is the script that gets new requests to be sent to Websocket Server:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST['identity'], $_POST['identifier'], $_POST['env'], $_POST['action'], $_POST['payload'])){
    $identity = $_POST['identity'];
    $identifier = $_POST['identifier'];
    $env = $_POST['env'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $payload = $_POST['payload'];

    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $client = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'ICU push');
    $client->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:21002');
    $client->send(json_encode(array('identity' => $identity, 'env' => $env, 'message' => formatRequest($identifier, $action, $payload))));
} else {
    echo "Invalid request";
    exit;
}
```

And the server start script:

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../autoload.php');

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer;
use ICU\Server;
use ICU\Logger;

$logger = new Logger();
$logger->setInteractive(true);

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$server  = new Server('test');

$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:21002");
$pull->on('message', array($server, 'onNewRequest'));
$logger->info("ZMQ listening on TCP 127.0.0.1:21002");

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(21001, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new IoServer(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new WampServer(
                $server
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$logger->info("ICU Server listening on 0.0.0.0:21001");

$loop->run();
```

The HTTP request itself doesn't fail. Response code is 200 and there are no errors in error log. Also when echoing through-out the script, I see the script gets executed fully but ZeroMQ won't send it to the Websocket server.

I checked with `netstat` and ports 21001 and 21002 are running and listening. Also I added `iptables` entries for both (though 21001 should be enough since ZeroMQ is only used on the local level but just in case).

This is a CentOS 7 server and I have libzmq installed along with the zmq pecl extension.

```
$ php -i | grep "zmq"
/etc/php.d/zmq.ini
zmq
libzmq version => 4.1.3
```

Have I missed something in my code or could this be a server configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of debugging, the issue fell to SELinux.

It seems that ZeroMQ connections get denied when SELinux is in `enforcing` mode.

For anyone encountering such issue, you need to disable SELinux:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```